# CPP Rest SDK http_listener throws exception in nano server (in a Docker container)

Tags: windows, docker, nano-server, cpprest-sdk

I have a server app built witn Cpp Rest SDK which runs fine in a windowsserver code Docker container (10GB!). Now I'm trying to make it work in a nano server container to save space (1GB "only"). The app runs but then in throws an exception during initialization.
More specifically it throws an "Unknown exception" on a pplx::task::wait().

```
http_listener m_listener;
auto task = m_listener->open();
task.wait(); // <= throws Unknown exception
```

Again, the above code works if run in a windowsservercore container.
Any clues?
Also can't find a way to debug the code remotely in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Without some more info about what the app does I'm not totally sure how to help with your specific issue.

Comment: ...won't let me edit after 5 mins...In the meantime, here is a [walk through of remote debugging in VS2015](https://www.richard-banks.org/2017/02/debug-net-in-windows-container.html).  Generally just so you know there are a lot of things that work in server but not nanoserver (that extra 9 GB ain't for nothing haha).  It's a work in progress on our end.  For future issues, if you tag with docker-for-windows we'll get to it faster. Cheers!